# Repetitive result in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working with some test codes in Javascript.  When I inserted the ..else {} in a IF statement within a for..loop, procedures under else{} should not be run if the statement is TRUE, but it is not happening.  The output is always displays the message "No place logged" even the statement is TRUE.

A beginner in Javascript here. :-)

this is the sample code.

```
function forLoops() {
  for (var x = 0; x < places.length; x++) {
  if(userInput === places[x]) {
    console.log("Your place input " + userInput + " is on our database.");
  } else {
    console.log("No place logged!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code seems correct. Do you in fact know that the condition is ever `true`? For example, if `userInput` is `"a"` and `places` is `["a", "b", "c"]`, the output is "No place logged! No place logged! Your place input a is in our database." Or did you mean to output just the last one and suppress "No place logged" if any element is equal to `userInput` - either one "No place logged" or one "Your place input a is in our database", not one for each row?

Comment: You can try alert of userInput and places[x] to check if they are actually equal.. just add alert(userInput); and alert(places[x]);

Comment: Since you're using `===` you need an exact match of both type and value.  Since Javascript doesn't make mistakes in this regard, it seems likely that your two values are indeed not actually the same.  Since you don't show the actual data, people can only guess what the issue is.  You need to see EXACTLY what the two pieces of data are (both type and value) so you can see why the `if` fails.

Comment: This question can't be answered without access to the data you are comparing.

Comment: "ah great!  I just use "==" instead of "===".  Thanks.  It's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `===` and not `==` which in javascript means equal and no type conversion.

so if userInput is NOT a number but maybe a string of a number "6" insead of 6, than its not equal.

check your function with `==`

Comment: Possible guess, but just a guess.

Comment: naturally, without full source code, i can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I should use `==` not `===` when declaring variables.

I realized it when trying and testing my code.

Answers above supported my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here userInput  is undefined according to your provided code

Another thing is that

if you use `===` it won't use conversion during checking. it is strict comparing but if you use `==` then it will done conversion and then comapare with each other.

try like this

```
function forLoops(userInput) {
  for (var x = 0; x < places.length; x++) {
  if(userInput === places[x]) {
    console.log("Your place input " + userInput + " is on our database.");
  } else {
    console.log("No place logged!");
    }
  }
}
```

pass user input to foorloop during calling

Comment: `userInput` could be a global variable, or a prisoner of a closure. It does not have to be undefined, depending on context.

Answer (score -1):

When using the `===` , you have to make sure that both operands are of the same type, in your case `'userInput'` and all elements contained in your array `'places'`. Try with `==` as suggested in the comments.